# How do I add Product Images as URL instead of uploading them in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I am making a fashion store in Magento. I have affiliation with many stores and I don't want to save their product images on my server because of space issue, they require a lots of space more than 30 GB.

I want to add an absolute path for images so I can save space on my server.

Current situation: I need to upload images into Magento folders (/media/... etc.)

Required: I can add any images path for a product

- www.imagesss.com/abc/23.jpg,
- www.123agesss.com/a13c/2343.jpg,
- www.ima1323gesss.com/ab32c/2sdsd33.jpg

Comment: so you will be fetching images from different website ie: Each product may have images linked to different websites right ?

Comment: My guess is you will grab the products via some sort of feed, parse the info and save it to your database. If you have a feed-parser, why not check if it already allows for external images, if not, see what it does with them in the code and modify it accordingly. I doubt you will be adding them manually and you haven't given enough info! This extension for example: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sell-ingram-micro-techdata-100-other-suppliers-products.html only allows external images and not for them to be saved to your store, so it saved the image url to your db.

Comment: If you have that much media from affiliates you should be able to afford a second server with less Cpu/memory and more disk space just to serve the images.

Comment: @Melvyn even if you do that, you've got to store the same images twice, and bother to keep them in sync with the master set of images.

Comment: @quickshiftin Read up on NFS or similar technologies. If you want product images stored elsewhere, use a CDN (built-in). But being able to reference images stored somewhere (maybe, maybe not next week) on the web is not a good idea. It drastically changes the number of ways your site can break. Instead of adding diskspace, you'll hire someone to check product images.

Comment: @Melvyn I'm pretty sure I just lost brain cells reading your comment... NFS is not the answer here, nor is a CDN. Having Magento be able to accept a URL instead of an image is what we're looking for.

Comment: @quickshiftin Well, if you think you need that, build it. But to reference one image on multiple hostnames, both NFS and built-in CDN support work. The difference being that on NFS the image is stored on one physical disk and shared across image servers, whereas CDN's replicate content to multiple physical machines (and disks). In both cases, Magento generates one URL and proxy (NFS/image servers) or DNS segmentation (CDN) picks the right physical.

Comment: you can create the product attirbute of text type 
add that url in that field and write the custom code to display product image